# Is there any way to log queries and output to a file?

Tags: mysql, batch-processing

My case is the following: an external party delivers a huge SQL file with thousands of queries. These include updates, inserts, subqueries, etc. Those queries are assembled in third-party software (I think Excel, but I might be mistaken).

As a result, many of these queries tend to fail and the whole batch needs to succeed without one single error. I'm using `mysql source file.sql` to execute the queries, and I'm using `mysql tee log.txt` to log the output to a txt-file.

However, this has proven to be insufficient, as this is the output I'm getting:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

It's kinda looking for a needle in a haystack. I'd have to count all the preceding logging messages to determine which exact query failed.

Is there any way to get a log file *including* the queries? Or is there another way of doing this efficiently?

- Executing in small batches is not an option. (It would take ages.)
- Executing them all on the commandline isn't either. (The messages fly by so fast it's impossible to read or capture them all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the mysql client with to `-v` or `--verbose` flag, it will echo the statement as well as the output.

```
$ mysql -v
mysql> tee output.txt
mysql> source myscript.sql
```

---

Update:

Note in the documentation for the `--tee` option (or the `tee` command):

> Tee functionality works only in interactive mode.

This means it doesn't work when you run a script, and this limitation is documented. In other words, it works if you use `source` as you are doing, but it doesn't work if you do this:

```
$ mysql -v --tee output.txt < myscript.sql
```

Comment: Thanks @Sherlock, I added the extra detail here because [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327501) described trouble doing tee in non-interactive mode. I wanted to supplement my answer here to keep the info together.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your query script as per below for each statement:

```
echo "update mytable set col1='value' where id='id'" >> C:\Backup\error.txt
update mytable set col1='value' where id='id' >> C:\Backup\error.txt 2>&1
```

Note: If your are executing on linux then change path etc. accordingly.

Comment: Oh, that's very nice. I assume that there's no way to log it to a variable log file? Like `>> the tee file` or something? But this is good as-is, thanks.