# MySQL tee out.log works from client, but coming up blank when run in a script

Tags: mysql, tee

When I run the following for the mysql> promt:

```
USE database;
TEE out.log;
UPDATE...query...
```

the result ends up in out.log as expected. 
However when running the following command from CLI:

```
mysql -u user -pSECRET --tee out.log database < query.sql
```

out.log comes up blank. I've also tried

```
mysql -u user -pSECRET database < query.sql > out.log
```

with the same result (blank file). I'm having a heck of a time figuring out why. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to log queries and output to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286004/is-there-any-way-to-log-queries-and-output-to-a-file)

Comment: Thanks Bill, but when I added the -v flag (per accepted answer at the link you mentioned) I'm now seeing the statement output to the screen, but not in the file. Also I'm not seeing the result in either the file, or on the screen

Comment: FYI here is what the updated query looked like: mysql -u user -pSECRET -v --tee out.log database < query.sql

Comment: mysql -u user -pSECRET -v database < query.sql > out.log logs statement but no result either

Comment: I have added an explanation that it doesn't work in interactive mode in the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue, here's what finally worked for me:

Put the following in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.sql
do
  mysql -u user -pSECRET -v database < $file
done
```

Then run the script with

```
sh run.sh > logfile 2>&1
```

This runs all my queries, and shows the

```
Query OK, xx rows affected;
```

or whatever errors come up in my logfile. Hope this saves the next guy a few hours.